# Minimizing charge frequency and declines

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an app that behaves in the following way: users have sessions, lasting about 1-3 hours. During that session, users make an indeterminate number of purchases. Suppose further that some users can compensate other users for their purchases, e.g. as a user, I could pay for some percentage of your purchases. What I want to do is minimize the total number of credit card charges, and maximize the probability that all charges succeed.

**Concrete Example:**

There are two users and three time periouds: `u1`, `u2`, and `t1`, `t2`, `t3` respectively. In `t1`, `u1` and `u2` make a $10 purchase. In `t2`, `u1` makes a $20 purchase. In `t3`, `u2` compensates `u1` for $5 of the `t2` purchase. The amounts are represented in this table:

```
    |  t1  |  t2  |  t3  |
----|------|------|------|
u1  | $10  |  $20 | -$5  |
u2  | $10  |  $0  |  $5  |
```

**Simple Solution 1: Everyone gets a charge!**

Create a charge capture for the original amount each time someone makes a purchase and then simply charging less if someone's purchase is compensated. In this solution, the above problem results in 4 separate charges (one for each purchase and one for the 'compensation'). The problem with this is that, effectively, I am running four charges, but there were only three purchases. I am maximizing the probability of a successful transaction, but charges are not minimized.

**Simple Solution 2: Sums**

Save all purchases and payments in a database, aggregate them after `t3`, and then place single large charges for the aggregate amounts. The problem with this is that users may run up against account limits, and I don't know until I place the large charges. E.g. suppose `u1` has $20 of credit, even if I check that each of his purchases will go through individually, the aggregate will fail. By the time that I aggregate, the user has already received what he purchased, and now I'm liable for the failed transaction. (Obviously not good.)

**Complicated Solution 1: Everyone gets a capture!**

When `u1` and `u2` make their initial $10 purchases, I create a $50 capture on each of their cards. Subsequent purchases in `t2` get aggregated with the purchases in `t1`. Hence, `u1` and `u2` both have a single charge of $25 and $15 respectively. This is nice in that payments success is high, and I'm only running two charges. The problem with this is that I don't know what amount to capture at `t1`. Suppose that subsequent `t2` purchases exceeded the captured amount; now I have to create new charges in `t2` and we are back to the simple solution 1.

**Complicated Solution 2: Rolling sum captures**

In `t1` create captures for each of the user's purchases. In `t2`, refund the captures made in `t1` but then aggregate the `t1` and `t2` purchases into new captures. Repeat in step three. Hence, in `t1` each user has a $10 capture, in `t2` those are refunded and replaced by a $30 and $10 capture, in `t3` they get a $30 and $15 capture. After `t3` is finished, they get a $25 and $15 charge. This seems like the best solution, but there are a lot of captures and refunds, and maybe this is bad for some reason that I don't understand yet.

Are there better/other solutions to this situation that I haven't thought of? Is there something wrong with complicated solution 2 that I cant see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated Solution 2 should work, although there's a risk that making too many charges on the same card in a short period of time could trigger fraud detection algorithms.

I'd recommend reaching out to Stripe's support directly at https://support.stripe.com/email. They have specialists that should be able to help you decide on the best payment flow for your app.

Comment: FYI: Stripe support agreed with you.